# iphone SDK: How to post data to a url?

Tags: objective-c, http-post, ios5

This may be a duplicate question but i could not find my answer when searching. So, How do i post data to a url? Heres what i got so far:

```
NSString *url = @"https://localhost/login.php";
NSURL *urlr = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlre = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];


[urlre setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
NSUserDefaults *defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *user = [defs stringForKey:@"User"];
NSString *pass = [defs stringForKey:@"Pass"];
NSInteger *version = [defs integerForKey:@"Version"];


NSString *bodyData = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"user=%@&password=%@&version=%d",user,pass,version];
NSData *body = [bodyData dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;


[urlre setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlre setValue:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",[body length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[urlre setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[urlre setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *dataThis = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlre returningResponse:&response error:&error];

if(dataThis)
{
    NSLog(@"Connect Success");
} else {
    NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Is the above correct? In my

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

event, I get nothing. Even in the didFinishLoading it gets nothing with NSLog. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set a delegate for your request?

Why don't you have a look at using a framework like ASIHTTPRequest, makes things so simple. Check it out http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: I think your compile errors are because ASIHTTP is not ARC compliant. What you do is is click on your project -> project name under TARGETS -> BUILD PHASES -> COMPILE SOURCES and then select all the ASIHTTP files, hit enter, a dialog box will pop up, paste this into the compile flags box -fno-objc-arc You should be good to go then.